# C++ Custom Vector Class: Pointer Behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am writing a custom vector class for a course. We are supposed to implement a push_back function that reallocates new memory when the initial array is full. My implementation should work, however when printing the values I always get a "0" as first element, despite pointing to a place in memory where another value is stored. It do not find my mistake, or what is going on here. The other values work.

Here is the code:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using std::size_t;

class Vector{
  double* data;         //array to store the data
  size_t sz;            //count number of elements in the vector 
  size_t max_sz;        //max elements

public:
  // constructor default max_sz is set to 5
  Vector(size_t n): sz{0}, max_sz{n < 5? 5: n}, data{new double[n]}{}

  double* begin() { return this->data; }  // return a pointer to the first element 

  Vector(std::initializer_list<double> data): Vector(data.size()){
    for(const auto &elem: data){
      this->data[sz++] = elem;
    }
  }
  ~Vector(){ delete[] this->data; }  //destructor

  size_t size() const { return this->sz; }
  size_t capacity() const { return max_sz; };

  double* at(size_t position) { return this->begin() + position; }  //convenience function

  void reset(double* new_data) {this->data = new_data; }    //reset pointer to new array

  void push_back(double value){
     //test if array is "full"
     if (this->size() == this->capacity()) {

    // create a new temp array, copy the values reset the pointer and delete
    Vector temp(this->capacity() * 2);

    //copy elements from this->data to temp
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->size(); i++) {
      *(temp.at(i)) = *(this->at(i));
    }

    *(temp.at(this->size())) = value;   //"push_back" the value

    //control statements
    std::cout << temp.begin() << " " << *(temp.begin()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "/* message */" << '\n';

    this->reset(temp.begin());   //reset the pointer from this->data to temp

    //more control statements
    std::cout << this->begin() << " " << *(this->begin()) <<'\n';        
    std::cout << "/* message */" << '\n';

    this->sz++;       // increase size

    this->max_sz = temp.capacity();       // update capacity

  } else {
    // stuff to follow
  }
 }
};
```

Now to main:

```
#include "vector.h"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  Vector a{1,2,3,4,5};   //usie initializer list

  a.push_back(6);        //call push_back 

  //control statements, the same will be call from within push_back
  //this is the core problem, because a.begin() references to the same memory as this->begin()
  //from within a.push_back(), but the values are different. 
  //How can the same memory block save two different values?
  std::cout << a.begin() << " " << *(a.begin()) << '\n';

  //to show that the rest actually works:
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << *(a.begin()+i) << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x560db3004ea0 1
/* message */
0x560db3004ea0 1
/* message */
0x560db3004ea0 0
0
2
3
4
5
6
```

I mean, how is this possible. It's the same place in memory, why is there a 1 when called from inside the push_back function, and a "0" when call from main, despite poiting to the same place in memory?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unrelated: I don't think you'd loose performance if you'd used a `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: `this->reset(temp.begin());` You are assigning to a pointer that goes away when `temp` is deleted (goes out of scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears that both `temp` and `this` own the pointer to the same `data` after `this->reset(temp.begin());` and then `temp` goes out of scope making access to `this->data` undefined behavior.

The fix is to call

```
temp->reset(nullptr);
```

before temp goes out of scope so that the destructor does not free the `data`.